# Read unknown additional fields with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-3

I have a table, which is mapped with NHibernate:

```
 Person
 ------
 Firstname
 Lastname
```

There is also a DTO which is called `Person`.

Now, there are possibilities, that there are more fields, than known at design-time. The user can add customer defined fields at runtime. In this case, there are generated additional fields to my table (this is historically and I cannot change this).

The "new" table is looking now like:

```
Person
------
Firstname
Lastname
IF_Field1
IF_Field2
```

Now, I am searching a way to get this values (from IF_Field1, IF_Field2 etc) with NHibernate into the DTO `Person`. For example as a Hashtable or something similar.

Is there a way to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at dynamic components:
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#components-dynamic

Comment: See also http://ayende.com/blog/3942/nhibernate-mapping-dynamic-component. But it won't work because the property names need to be known and mapped.